# winforms how to paint (fillRectangle) a single cell in TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

hi
in winforms how to paint (fillRectangle) a single cell in TableLayoutPanel ?
without using other panels please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the CellPaint event. 
As an example:

```
    private void tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == 0 && e.Column == 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.CellBounds);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `e.ClipRectangle` to `e.CellBounds` and this will be the right answer ;) (ClipRectangle refers to the whole panel)