# Paint a single cell (or a single row) in a JTable without the renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, render

I have a JTable and i want a cell (or its row) painted in red when the value entered is higher than a certain value. I'm checking that into a TableModelListener to detect TableChange, so I see no way of colouring the table at the renderer (yet I'm sure it is possible, only it is unknown for me).

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031245/winforms-how-to-paint-fillrectangle-a-single-cell-in-tablelayoutpanel) but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: no relation to the question you referenced - JTable is Swing, TableWhatever in the other is ... ?

Comment: yet not read snoracles swing tutorial? 1) you always need a renderer 2) you don't color the renderer, you color the rendering component: that's done by a custom renderer which configures the component's visual properties depending on context, f.i. on the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that job for [prepareRendered](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29) as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650734/how-to-gray-out-non-editable-cell-in-jtable/6656279#6656279)

Answer (score 0):

Following is for single table cell you can extend it for row:

First take table column you want to pint and then add a `TableCellRenderer` to it as follows:

```
    TableColumnModel columnModel = myTable.getColumnModel();
    TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(5); // Give column index here
    column.setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
```

Make MyTableCellRendere class which implements TableCellRenderer and extends JLabel(so that we can give a background color to it). It will look something like following:

```
public class MyTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int col) {
        JLabel jLabel = (JLabel) value;
        setBackground(jLabel.getBackground());
        setForeground(UIConstants.black);
        setText(jLabel.getText());
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now in method where you are listening table cell value change do something like follow:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(changedValue);
// check for some condition
label.setBackground(Color.red); // set color based on some condition
myTable.setValueAt(label, 0, 5); // here 0 is rowNumber and 5 is colIndex that should be same used to get tableColumn before.
```

Comment: could be, but that's not the point. Read the tutorial to learn how to do visual config correctly ;-) downvoted